# Connecting to cloudant from java using TLSv1.2

Tags: java, tls1.2, cloudant

I'm trying to connect to my Cloudant database from Java using TLSv1.2 from Liberty server running IBM JRE.

Support for connection lower than TLSv1.2 is ending and I need this working.

I added a `customSSLSocketFactory` to the builder configured for TLSv1.2 communication , when I run it in my local environment, which runs on Oracle JRE there is no error , but when I run it on a newer environment, which runs the Liberty server with IBM JRE (latest versions Java 8) I get an error.

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory; 
try {
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
    }
    X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

    SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    ssl.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, new SecureRandom());
    sslSocketFactory = ssl.getSocketFactory();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

client = ClientBuilder.url(new URL(restServerURL)).username(userid)
         .password(password).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).customSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
         .build();
```

Error received is:

```
R java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform@5194035f, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
R   at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:654)
R   at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(OkHttpsURLConnection.java:63)
R   at com.cloudant.http.internal.interceptors.SSLCustomizerInterceptor.interceptRequest(SSLCustomizerInterceptor.java:71)
R   at com.cloudant.http.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:290)
R   at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:485)
R   at com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient.executeRequest(CloudantClient.java:339)
R   at com.cloudant.client.internal.views.ViewRequester.executeRequestWithResponseAsJson(ViewRequester.java:34)
R   at com.cloudant.client.internal.views.ViewRequester.getResponseAsJson(ViewRequester.java:28)
R   at com.cloudant.client.internal.views.ViewRequestImpl.getResponse(ViewRequestImpl.java:34)
R   at com.profility.database.cloudant.CloudantConnector.getQuestionnaire(CloudantConnector.java:470)
R   at com.profility.database.Database.getQuestionnaire(Database.java:159)
R   at com.profility.questionnaire.QuestionnaireCache.getTheQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireCache.java:21)
R   at com.profility.scheduer.ApplicationStarter.run(ApplicationStarter.java:31)
R   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom SSLSocketFactory to use TLS1.2 you just need to configure your JVM to provide TLSv1.2.

Likely you just need the property as described in this [support document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html) `com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true` to match the Oracle behaviour and enable TLS 1.0, 1.1. and 1.2 (instead of the default of just 1.0).

If that is insufficient you may need the properties described in this [support document](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1022279) to enable the TLSv1.2 for the protocols.